# how to block duplicates while pushing data into an array of objects using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying add div elements dynamically using ng-repeat.

```
    <div class="dynamicRow">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input class="form-control" ng-disabled="true" type="text" ng-model='item.name' id='item-{{$index}}' class='input-{{$index}}'/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If I use ng-repeat with track by item.id, it is not allowing duplicates but once i get the duplicate exception, after that i am not able to add any new item as well.

```
  $scope.items=[];

  $scope.addAnother = function(){

    if ($scope.items.length < 10) {
              $scope.items.push({  
                  "id": $scope.userid,  
                  "name": $scope.username  
              });
             }
    
    }
```

This function is called on a button click.
Items is in the form of
items=[{id: "001", name: "A PLUS"}, {id: "0012", name: "TEST"}, {id: "0013", name: "Another Test"}]
The data here is dynamic , only when button is clicked, the data is pushed. Now with the code, duplicates are not allowed but then if it encounters a duplicate, then i am not able to add any other value also.

Comment: "How should i proceed?" Well, what do you want to do with duplicates? To block them, simply add an `if` statement in your JS code to check if `item` already exists in `items`, then simply don't push it

Comment: @Alekshey Solovey : Thats  fine, but now with the code, whenever i encounter a duplicate value, its freezes, like i am not able to add any other value as well and getting 
 "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys" exception everytime. How to handle this

Comment: you can try to use `track by $index`, your `id` is duplicated, but not the unique index of each item